# Python Memory error calling exec

Tags: python, arrays, memory, numpy

I new to python and below is my code,

```
import numpy as np 

val = 4**10
Q = []
for j in range(60):
    a = []
    for i in range(val):
        tmp = (i+j)**2
        a.append(tmp)
    Q.append(a)
T= zip(*Q)
G = []
for t in T:
    tmps2 = np.average(t)
    G.append(tmps2)
```

Below is my code error:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glo
b, loc)
    169             else:
    170                 filename = fname
--> 171             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    172     else:
    173         def execfile(fname, *where):

C:\Users\User\Desktop\simpl.py in <module>()
     13
     14
---> 15 T= zip(*Q)
     16
     17 G = []

MemoryError:
```

So, can any expert explain to me, my computer still has about 1.5GB memory available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this much more efficiently with:

```
i,j= np.indices((60, 4**10))
Q = (i+j)**2
G = np.average(Q, axis=0)
```

The biggest advantages are:

- avoid the for loops
- more efficient memory usage.

In this example the transpose of `Q` is not used, so you will probably not get the memory error.

Comment: `i, j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(60), np.arange(4**10), indexing='ij', sparse=True)` is equivalent to np.indices and saves a little more memory

Comment: Dear Saullo and jtaylor, Thanks for the suggestion, it solve my problem. May i know, why in my code it will run out of memory, but using np.indices or np,meshgrid will not have such problem. Also, my pc still have about 1.5GB ram free. (I using windows 8.1, python 2.7.6). thanks.

Comment: @user3751276 the problem with your code is that it uses lists to store the big matrices. Each element in the list is probably more than 64bits long while using indices you will get 32 bits per stored element. In your version you store the transposed Q matrix, dublicating the required space. The 1.5GB of memory may not be sufficient to store all this. Are you using Python 2.7.6 64 Bit?

Comment: Dear Saullo, i using Python 2.7.6 32bit. sincerely thank for your advice and suggestion. thanks.

Comment: @user3751276 if you use Python 64 Bits you will not get the memory error, because the 32 Bits version is limited to about 2GB memory usage, even if your machine has more available...